# UWP: Authenticate user using a smart card

Tags: uwp, certificate, smartcard

I need to write some UWP functionality that can authenticate a user from a TPM virtual smart card. Ideally I would like to utilize a popup like the one that occurs in the browser that asks you to select a certificate and then prompts you for a pin if it is tied to a smart card like the one below.

[image]

I have the following code from the post found here: [User login with Smart Card for Windows UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373052/user-login-with-smart-card-for-windows-uwp-app) but I am experiencing the same issue when trying to sign "Provider could not perform the action since the context was acquired as silent."

```
ReadOnlyList<Certificate> Certs;
        CertificateQuery CertQuery = new CertificateQuery();
        CertQuery.HardwareOnly = true;

        Certs = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(CertQuery);
        string strEncrypt = "test";
        IBuffer BufferToEncrypt = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

        foreach (Certificate Cert in Certs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Cert: {Cert.Subject}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Storagename: {Cert.KeyStorageProviderName}");
            if (Cert.HasPrivateKey && ((Cert.KeyStorageProviderName == "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider") || Cert.KeyStorageProviderName == "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider"))
            {
                CryptographicKey Key = null;

                try
                {
                    Key = await PersistedKeyProvider.OpenKeyPairFromCertificateAsync(Cert, HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1, CryptographicPadding.RsaPkcs1V15);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Got keypair");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not open Smart Card Key Pair
                    Debug.WriteLine("Could not open Smart Card Key Pair");
                }

                if (Key != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Try to Sign with Cert Private key 
                        IBuffer EncryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(Key, BufferToEncrypt);                            
                        Debug.WriteLine("Signing successful");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Could not sign   
                        Debug.WriteLine("Could not sign");
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to produce the same popup? Do I have to build it myself? If not, If I choose a certificate programatically, how can I prompt for a pin and verify it?

I'm looking for the functionality shown above that is also similar to the  KeyChain.ChoosePrivateKeyAlias and IKeyChainAliasCallback that exists in Android that allows a user to pick a certificate if anybody is familiar with that as well.

*Edit 1*

Changing the line:

```
IBuffer EncryptedBuffer = await CryptographicEngine.Sign(Key, BufferToEncrypt);
```

to

```
IBuffer EncryptedBuffer = await CryptographicEngine.SignAsync(Key, BufferToEncrypt);
```

does prompt me for a pin but I still need to figure out the popup for the certificate selection vs. selecting it programmatically.

*Edit 2*
You can show the "Select a Certificate" window by using

```
        CredentialPickerOptions options = new CredentialPickerOptions();
        options.AuthenticationProtocol = AuthenticationProtocol.Ntlm;
        options.Message = "Please select your certificate";
        options.Caption = "Select a Certificate";
        options.TargetName = ".";
        options.CredentialSaveOption = CredentialSaveOption.Hidden;

        CredentialPickerResults credentialsPicked = await 
        CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options);
```

However, the *CredentialPickerResults* has a *Credential* field which is of type *IBuffer*. I am unclear what I am supposed to do with this to either obtain the certificate directly or use it to do a lookup in the certificate store to get the certificate that was selected.